# Back screen connecting Android VNC Viewer by RealVNC with Ubuntu 22.04 Remote Desktop

Tags: android, remote-desktop, vnc

I just installed **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** and I'm trying to connect **Android VNC Viewer by RealVNC** as I did with Ubuntu 20.04 and it doesn't work correctly, I only see a **BLACK SCREEN** on Android, however:

1. Android VNC Viewer asks me for the **password** and the answer **is ok**.
2. The **mouse moves** on the Ubuntu screen when I move the touch on the VNC client in Android.
3. When I type something in Android **the text appears in Ubuntu**.

The Ubuntu Remote Desktop is configured like this:

```
Remote Desktop: Enabled
Enable Legacy VNC Protocol: Enabled (Require a password)
UserName: user
Password: pasword
And nothing else...
```

I hope someone can help me with this black screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a similar problem with vino-server on Ubuntu 22.04. The server is running and listening on port 5900. When I try to connect to the server from my Mac using RealVNC viewer it tries to connect with an unencripted connection, but nothing happens. Hopefully knows someone a solution ?
Best regards,PaulB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today (2022-04-30), RealVNC doesn't support Wayland which Ubuntu 22.04 uses by default so you need to disable it as per RealVNC's Ubuntu instructions [here](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002253198-Installing-and-Removing-VNC-Connect#downloading-vnc-server-0-20):

"Wayland is not supported, so if the remote computer is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS+, edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file, uncomment `WaylandEnable=false`, and reboot in order to remotely access the login screen."

Comment: OpenJDK ava.awt.Robot also [fails to capture screen](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8269245) on Ubuntu 22.04. Due to Wayland. There is a path but for some reason they don't accept it yet. I'm disabling Wayland in my server for the time being until other projects familiarize more with it.

Answer (score 2):

realvnc can actually visit ubuntu 22 default screen sharing. Just right click the connection setting -> properties -> options -> general -> picture quality, change to High.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not able to provide an answer but I can contribute with another side effect which may lead to think that it is a bug to be fixed by the dev team.

Using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Android app the application is able to connect successfully using the "ms-rd" URL. However a distorted image is shown and no input is recognized.